# Form with Custom Component does not recognize control

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-forms, angular-template-form

I am using a custom component (custom-text) which has the below code

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'custom-text, [custom-text]',
      templateUrl: './custom-text.template.html',
      styleUrls: ['./custom-text.component.scss']
    })
    export class CustomTextComponent implements OnInit {


      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }

Inside the custom-text.template.html

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput 
            id="controlid" 
            name="controlname" 
            maxlength="8"
            [(ngModel)]="value">
    </mat-form-field>
```

When I include this control inside a form (template-driven) on another component.

```
    <form #someForm="ngForm">
        <div custom-text></div>
    </form>

or 

<form #someForm="ngForm">
    <custom-text></custom-text>
</form>
```

I am unable to get the instance of the control using someForm.controls['controlId']

What am i doing wrong.

Comment: A Custom from control must be implements ControlValueAccessor, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009149/creating-custom-form-controls-in-angular-2?rq=1

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you for helping me with this, however, when I am using this with a mat-form-field it does not work as expected, the parent form does not consider this control as part of it.

Comment: I put below how make a custom control validators based in a input mat

Comment: I add another response not using a custom form control. In the stackblitz you has the two options

Answer (score 1):

I leave in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrcu35?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html) the most simple custom form control based in material input.

As you see implements ControlValueAccessor, that's has the functions:

```
onChange:any; //declare this function to indicate in any time that you change the value
onTouched:any; //declare this function to indicate in any time that your compoment is touched

 writeValue(value: any[]|any): void {
    this.value=value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled=isDisabled
  }
```

And a provider like

```
   {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomMat),
      multi: true
    }
```

If you want to make a validation inside the component, you need add a new provider

```
   {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomMat),
      multi: true,
    }
```

And create the function validate

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null{
      //your logic here
      return null;
  }
```

I used this two more functions:

```
setValue(value: any){
    this.value=value;
    this.onChange(value);

  }
  focusOut()
  {
    this.onTouched()
  }
```

To call a change and a touched functions

***Updated 01.04.20*** well, the problem of this custom material input is that the error can not see reflected in the input, so we are going to make some change

The idea is add a customError matcher

```
export class CustomFieldErrorMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  constructor(private customControl: AbstractControl,private errors:any) { }

  isErrorState(control: AbstractControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return this.customControl && this.customControl.touched && this.customControl.invalid;
  }
}
```

That's our inner input is invalid if the control is invalid. Well, are a dificult that is know what is the this "control". For this, in ngAfterViewInit we inject the NgControl, and this ngControl will be our control, puff

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const ngControl: NgControl = this.injector.get(NgControl, null);
    if (ngControl) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.control = ngControl.control;
         this.matcher = new CustomFieldErrorMatcher(this.control,null);
      })
    }
  }
```

At least add this matcher

```
  <input name="input" matInput [ngModel]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="setValue($event)" 
    [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" >
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrcu35-efypg7?file=app%2Fcustom-mat.ts)

Comment: injecting the `ngControl` is the best "puff" I saw. With this my components are now compatible with template driven forms AND react form controls. The only thing I don't understand is why we need the `setTimeout()`?

Comment: it's only to avoid the initial error: Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Answer (score 0):

thinking about your problem really you needn't make a custom form component, just a component that pass as input the form control. Just add an Input

```
@Input() control
//And in .html
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput 
            id="controlid" 
            name="controlname" 
            maxlength="8"
            [formControl]="control">
</mat-form-field>
```

You use the component like

```
<form #someForm="ngForm">
    <div custom-text [control]="someForm.controls['controlId']"></div>
</form>
```