# Custom Formcomponent with ControlValueAccessor/Validator has asynchronous update of control inside validate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-form-validation

Inside my angular app I generated a component that serves as a custom `FormControl` and it implements `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validator`.

That component is used inside a `FormGroup` and it has a validator attached to it (like its value must have at least 10 chars or w/e). When theres a value change inside the actual `input` inside my custom `FormControl` the `validate` method triggers. Inside this method I can access the `FormControl` but it has a "pre-change-state" i.e. if the user typed in something wrong (according to the bound validator) it gives me its last value/error/state...

To get to the updated state I'm using a hacky

```
setTimeout(()=>{// code goes here},0);
```

How can I get the updated state inside `validate` without `setTimeout`? Or is there something like an `afterUpdate` hook I am not aware of?

Here's my stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-tubfwx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-form-control%2Fcustom-form-control.component.ts

Comment: I think that your approach is correct. You need give Angular a breath to give it time to setError to the inner mat-input. Another aproach can be use a custom error Matcher: that's say to Angular that the inner mat-input has error if the formControl has error, see this (updated) SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862011/form-with-custom-component-does-not-recognize-control/55864917#55864917

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it and respond back.